# How to use tap gesture in Accessibility in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer, tap, uiaccessibility

I'm working on app for blind people first i needed to use swipe gesture and after search i can do it by using

```
 override func accessibilityScroll( direction:       
 UIAccessibilityScrollDirection)-> Bool {
 if direction == UIAccessibilityScrollDirection.Left
 {
   Do what you want to do 
   }
 }
```

Now I need to use tap gesture and I can't find any function to use make custom tap in Accessibility can anyone help me pleasee!
Thanks